# can I create addresses based on what I want to look like?

Tags: address

Hi I am completely new to bitcoin. I was wondering if it is possible to create addresses based on how the final outcome you would like to be. For example, I dont like something like that 1L5gu6zJHxtAiDM74heP7wW84PYQ5Ltc9o as it is extremely difficult to remember. Could it be possible to create something like that eg., 1L5a5a5a5a5a...c9o i.e. decide the final letters or an approximation?

Comment: Look into vanity addresses, it should be pretty close to what you're looking for. VanityGen is the most popular.

Comment: @m1xolyd1an That's indeed the right answer, but it only lets you control a few characters, so it hardly helps for memorability.

Answer (score -1):

Not really, a Bitcoin address is the result of applying multiple hash functions to a public key. Since you can't decide how the result of a hash function will look like depending on the input, you won't be able to do so with a Bitcoin address.

You can find the Bitcoin address creation process explained in [the Bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses).

However, as commented by @m1xolyd1an and @pieter-wuille, [VanityGen](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Vanitygen) can be used to create a more personalised address, instead of a purely random one. Since VanityGen is based on a probabilistic search, the pattern that you will be able to include in your address will be quite short. Trying to include long patters requires a lot of time, becoming infeasible.

> [image]